# How can I make it so when I press a JButton it checks whether you entered something in JTextFeild is right or wrong? (Just like a lock in Java)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Sorry if this question has already been answered somewhere or if I don't make sense, but I was wondering if I can create a 'lock' on a JPanel. So far I have made it so when I press the button it clears everything and a JLabel appears. However, I can't make it so when I type something into the JTextField, JAVA checks whether whatever I typed into the text field matches the 'correct' username. The only way I can make the JLabel appear is through the console, and I don't want that to happen. I want it so when I type something into the JTextField to check it. I have heard that you can add a KeyListener or addActionListener to the button, but how can I implement those in?

Again, I am just a beginner in JAVA and am not sure I'm doing something wrong, but I was just confused, so if you could help me that would greatly appreciated!

Here is my code

```
package Story;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Login {

public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login Page");
frame.setSize(300, 150);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.add(panel);
placeComponents(panel);

frame.setVisible(true);

}

private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

panel.setLayout(null);

JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
panel.add(userLabel);

JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
panel.add(userText);

JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
panel.add(loginButton);

JButton registerButton = new JButton("register");
registerButton.setBounds(180, 80, 80, 25);
panel.add(registerButton);


   loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
   {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           loginButton.setVisible(false);

           registerButton.setVisible(false);

           userText.setVisible(false);

           userLabel.setVisible(false);

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
Scanner user = new Scanner (System.in);
String name = user.nextLine();
String accept = "Kenny";
String good; 

if (name.equals(accept)) {
good = "Welcome";

} else {
good = "False. Error";
} 
JLabel label1 = new JLabel(good);
label1.setBounds(100, 40, 100, 100);
       label1.setVisible(true);           
       panel.add(label1);

}


   });
}
}
```

Comment: Is checking field input when 'enter' key' is what you want ? Or when would you like it to be checked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking input from console while checking it, then how are you expecting it to you proper result.

Change below line :

```
String name = user.nextLine();
```

to

```
String name = userText.getText();
```

You should get the text which user has entered.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, and I appreciate the quick response.